# Gitlab on an OpenVZ Server with nginx - Authentication Required popup

Tags: nginx, gitlab, openvz

I am experiencing an issue where trying to access GitLab through my browser is providing me with a popup for Authentication. It looks like a .htaccess authentication popup, but I have not configured htaccess authentication with my nginx configuration.

### Authentication Required

```
    The server at http://git.servername.com:80 requires a username and password.
    The server says: Password Protected.
    Username:
    Password:
```

I have tried troubleshooting this issue for a couple of days now, but I am running into some dead ends, since I see no information in my nginx error logs, or my GitLab production.log.

I recently performed an installation of GitLab on Ubuntu 12.04 (following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-gitlab-as-your-very-own-private-github-clone), and ran into some issues with not having enough memory on OpenVZ. I created some fake swap to get over this hurdle, and I have verified that the GitLab server is running. My verification and configuration information is as follows:

### GitLab Verification

```
    user@server:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check               RAILS_ENV=production
    Checking Environment ...

    Git configured for git user? ... yes
    Has python2? ... yes
    python2 is supported version? ... yes

    Checking Environment ... Finished

    Checking GitLab Shell ...

    GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0)
    Repo base directory exists? ... yes
    Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
    Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
    Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
    post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
    post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects

    Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

    Checking Sidekiq ...

    Running? ... yes

    Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

    Checking GitLab ...

    Database config exists? ... yes
    Database is SQLite ... no
    All migrations up? ... yes
    GitLab config exists? ... yes
    GitLab config outdated? ... no
    Log directory writable? ... yes
    Tmp directory writable? ... yes
    Init script exists? ... yes
    Init script up-to-date? ... yes
    Projects have satellites? ... can't check, you have no projects
    Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
    Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
    Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.9.1)

    Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

### Environment Info

```
    user@server:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info         RAILS_ENV=production

    System information
    System:         Ubuntu 12.04
    Current User:   git
    Using RVM:      no
    Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
    Gem Version:    2.0.3
    Bundler Version:1.6.0
    Rake Version:   10.1.0

    GitLab information
    Version:        6.0.2
    Revision:       10b0b8f
    Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
    DB Adapter:     mysql2
    URL:            http://git.servername.com
    HTTP Clone URL: http://git.servername.com/some-project.git
    SSH Clone URL:  git@git.servername.com:some-project.git
    Using LDAP:     no
    Using Omniauth: no

    GitLab Shell
    Version:        1.7.0
    Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
    Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
    Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

### Nginx Configuration

In my default.conf file:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name git.servername.com;

            location / {
             proxy_pass http://git.servername.com:80;
            }
    }
```

### Hosts file on my personal machine (not my VPS)

```
 <IP Address of VPS>     git.servername.com
```